# Remote Desktop Connection for Mac cannot log in to Windows Terminal Server if user's password expired

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop

We have users that connect to a terminal server, TS1, from a variety of desktop clients.  We also have a domain password policy that expires passwords after a certain amount of time.  If a user's password expires over the weekend and they log in to the terminal server, one of two things happen --

1. If they're using the Windows Remote Desktop Client, they are prompted to change their password to a new one and allowed to log into the server.
2. If they connect using the Remote Desktop Connection for Mac client, their password is rejected and they are not given the opportunity to change their password, effectively locking them out until Monday morning if they don't have access to a Windows PC.

I don't have a Mac to test this behavior out myself, so I have to take their word for it.  What could explain the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the absolute latest [client for OSX](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18140)? The only real answer is that they're different products and that they're clearly not feature-identical. I've had a similar issue, and I ended up setting up a website for users to reset their domain passwords.

Comment: I have not verified that they have the latest client.  I have one user that might be capable of doing this for me.  I'll check with him and post back.